# How to work with a Json object and a calendar that provides input to the flutter request (REST API)

Tags: json, rest, flutter, dart

My class is responsible for generating a button on the screen where a calendar will appear when clicking the button where the date will be one (input to request)

My formattedDate variable already returns the date in the format required for the request ... It even updates normally every time I click the OK button on the calendar ...

My goal is that each time I click this button a new request will be made in my FutureBuilder.
But it doesn't happen

I've done some research but I can't find anything similar that anyone has ever done :/ 
Below is part of the code

```
class CalendarFood extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CalendarFoodState createState() => new _CalendarFoodState();
}


class _CalendarFoodState extends State<CalendarFood> {
var now = new DateTime.now();
TimeOfDay _time = new TimeOfDay.now();

Future<Null> _selectDate() async{
  final DateTime picked = await showDatePicker(
    context: context,
    initialDate: now,
    firstDate: new DateTime(2019),
    lastDate: new DateTime(2020),

  );

  String formatDate = DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy').format(now);
  if(picked != null && picked != now){
    print("Date Selected:$formatDate");

    setState(() {
     now = picked;

    });
  }
}
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  String formattedDate = DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy').format(now);

  Widget _listaItensComida(List<String> _itens){
      String aux = "";
      String aux2 = "";
      for (int i=0;i<_itens.length;i++){
        if (i>0){

        aux2 = "${_itens[i].substring(1)} \n";
        aux = (aux + aux2);
        } else {
        aux = "${_itens[i]} \n";        
        }
      }
      return Text(aux, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0));
  }


    return new Scaffold(
       appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Cardápio"),
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
      ),
      body: ListView(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  height: 50,
                  child: Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                          flex: 10, 
                          child: Container(
                            child: SafeArea(
                              child: RaisedButton(
                                child: const Text('Selecionar Data'),
                                onPressed: _selectDate,
                              ),
                            ),
                            ),
                          ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 50,
                  child: Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                          flex: 3, // 20%
                          child: Container(
                            child: Icon(Icons.fastfood, size: 30.0,),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          flex: 7, // 20%
                          child: Container(
                            child: Text("$formattedDate"),
                           // child: Text("09/08/2019"),
                          ),
                        )
                    ],
                  ),

                ),
                Container(
                  height: 50,
                  child: Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                          flex: 1, // 20%
                          child: Container(),
                        ),
                      Expanded(
                          flex: 4, // 20%
                          child: Container(
                            child: Text("Almoço", style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 18.0)),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          flex: 5, // 20%
                          child: Container(
                            child: Text("Jantar", style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 18.0)),
                          ),
                        )
                    ],
                  ),

                ),

              FutureBuilder<MenuFoodListModel>(
                      future: fetchPostFood(formattedDate),
                      builder: (context, snapshot){
                        if (snapshot.hasData){
                          List<String> _almoco = snapshot.data.noticiaListFood[0].descricao.split(",");
                          List<String> _jantar = snapshot.data.noticiaListFood[1].descricao.split(",");
                          return ListView(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Container(
                                height: 50,
                                child: Row(
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Expanded(
                                        flex: 1, 
                                        child: Container(),
                                      ),
                                    Expanded(
                                        flex: 4, 
                                        child: Container(
                                          child: _listaItensComida(_almoco),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      Expanded(
                                        flex: 5, 
                                        child: Container(
                                          child: _listaItensComida(_jantar),
                                        ),
                                      )
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ], 
                          );
                        } else if(snapshot.hasError){
                            return Text("Os Dados do Cardápio não forão inseridos", softWrap: true);
                        //  return Text("${snapshot.error}", softWrap: true);
                        }
                        return CircularProgressIndicator();
                      },
                    ),

                Container(
                  height: 50,
                  child: Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                          flex: 1, 
                          child: Container(),
                        ),
                      Expanded(
                          flex: 4, 
                          child: Container(
                            child: Text("_almoco"),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          flex: 5, 
                          child: Container(
                            child: Text("_jantar"),
                          ),
                        )
                    ],
                  ),

                ), 
              ], 
            ),

    );
  }
}



Future<MenuFoodListModel> fetchPostFood(String data) async {

  final response = await http.get('http://app.bambui.ifmg.edu.br/integracao/cardapio/retornarCardapiosPorData?data=${data}');
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    return MenuFoodListModel.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
  } else {
    throw Exception('Falha ao carregar um post');
  }
}


class MenuFoodListModel {

  final List<MenuFood> noticiaListFood;

  MenuFoodListModel({this.noticiaListFood});

  factory MenuFoodListModel.fromJson(List<dynamic> json) {
    List<MenuFood> results2 = [];
    for(int i = 0; i<json.length; i++){
      MenuFood _noticia2 = MenuFood(id: json[i]['id'], data: json[i]['data'], tiporefeicao: json[i]['tiporefeicao'], descricao: json[i]['descricao']);
      results2.add(_noticia2);
    }
    return MenuFoodListModel(noticiaListFood: results2);
  }
}

class MenuFood {
  final String id;
  final String data;
  final String tiporefeicao;
  final String descricao;
  MenuFood({this.id, this.data,this.tiporefeicao, this.descricao});
}
```

When I manually pass the date to my fetchPostFood it returns me the correct result (Example: 08/09/2019)
But my goal is to get the date typed in the calendar. I would be grateful if anyone could help, I'm still learning about flutter: D

Comment: please reference this https://flutter-academy.com/async-in-flutter-futurebuilder/ and  add the following code, so we can see all execute status of your async code : switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                case ConnectionState.none:
                  return new Text('Input a URL to start');
                case ConnectionState.waiting:
                  return new Center(child: new CircularProgressIndicator());
                case ConnectionState.active:
                  return new Text('');
                case ConnectionState.done:

Comment: please use "add comment" after revise your code so I can check again. thanks.

Comment: The rest of the code responsible for this request I just added to the post, the request is working as it should ... the only thing that is not working is the request according to the date input coming from the calendar ... and every each time the ok button is pressed, a new request should be launched ....
More on the link you sent I will already have a great help ... I read superficially, I will read with more emphasis now.

Comment: Thanks for the example documentation, solved my problem!